# Checking the continuity of a function.

Tags: functions

Let $\mathbb{B}^n$ the unit open balls (centered at $0$) of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the function $$f\colon\mathbb{B}^n\to\mathbb{R}\quad\text{defined as}\quad u\mapsto\sqrt{1-||u||^2}.$$

> **Question.** How can i prove that f is continuous?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open unit balls of $\mathbb R^n$ is the set :
$$\mathbb B^n = \{u \in \mathbb R^n : \|u\| < 1\} $$
Thus, since $f$ is defined over $\mathbb B^n$, it is trully well-defined and thus continuous, as the condition
$$1-\|u\|^2\geq 0 \; \forall u \in \mathbb B^n $$
holds. Another, more algebraic approach is given by Dbchatto67 in the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $:$ Define a function $g : \Bbb B^n \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by $g(u) = \|u\|,$ $u \in \Bbb B^n.$ Define another function $h : [-1,1] \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by $h(x) = \sqrt {1-x^2},$ $x \in [-1,1].$ Both the functions $g$ and $h$ are continuous in their respective domains. Now observe that $f = h \circ g.$

Answer (score 1):

Show that

$f:\mathbb{B}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$; $f(u)=||u||$
 is continuos.

Let $u, u_0 \in \mathbb{B}^n$:

We have $|||u||-||u_0||| \le ||u-u_0|| $.

$\epsilon >0$.

Choose $\delta =\epsilon$:

Then

$||u-u_0|| \lt \delta$ implies

$|||u||-||u_0||| \le ||u-u_0|| \lt \delta = \epsilon$.

Now consider the functions $g,h$ :

$g:$ $[0,1) \rightarrow [0,1)$; $g(x)= x^2$; and

$h(x): (0,1]  \rightarrow (0,1]$; $h(x)=\sqrt{1-x}$ which are both continuos, as is the composite function:

$h \circ g \circ f$.

Dabchatto67's argument.